# java runtime.exec() not working on tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, runtime.exec

`Runtime.exec()` not working on tomcat.

I have a problem in running a command from java web application. I used `runtime.exec()`. It's working fine at eclipse. But not working at all after deployed on tomcat. I think that `runtime.exec()` not working at all. Any idea?

I written at server side. I want to create a windows schedule task from runtime. Here is my code.

```
String l_Time = pData.getTimeStamp();
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start  SchTasks /Create " +
                "/SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN /TN \"TaskName\"" +
                " /TR \"D:/Test/Test.bat\" /ST 09:00\"");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while (true) {
    line = r.readLine();
    if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
}
p.waitFor();
int exitVal = p.exitValue();
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute something on the server where Tomcat lives? or on the client where the browser lives (that won't work)?

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to execute in Runtime.exec() then it will not work in client side

Comment: I used at server side.

Answer (score 0):

As [javaBeginner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19216843/1031945) answered, I would like to share some more on this topic.
You have not mentioned which is the command you are trying to run and error? I hope this helps you.
There are several reasons.

The class [java.lang.Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) features a static method called `getRuntime()`, which retrieves the current Java Runtime Environment.
There are four overloaded versions of the exec() command:

1. public Process exec(String command);
2. public Process exec(String [] cmdArray);
3. public Process exec(String command, String [] envp);
4. public Process exec(String [] cmdArray, String [] envp);

For each of these methods, a command -- and possibly a set of arguments -- is passed to an operating-system-specific function call. This subsequently creates an operating-system-specific process (a running program) with a reference to a Process class returned to the Java VM. The Process class is an abstract class, because a specific subclass of Process exists for each operating system.

You can pass three possible input parameters into these methods:

1. A single string that represents both the program to execute and any arguments to that program
2. An array of strings that separate the program from its arguments
3. An array of environment variables

The first pitfall relating to `Runtime.exec()` is the [`IllegalThreadStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalThreadStateException.html).
The prevalent first test of an API is to code its most obvious methods. For example, to execute a process that is external to the Java VM, we use the `exec()` method. To see the value that the external process returns, we use the `exitValue()` method on the [`Process` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). In our first example, we will attempt to execute the Java compiler (javac.exe):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BadExecJavac
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {            
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("javac");
        int exitVal = proc.exitValue();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    } catch (Throwable t)
      {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
}
```

A run of BadExecJavac produces:

```
D:\progs>java BadExecJavac
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
    at java.lang.Win32Process.exitValue(Native Method)
    at BadExecJavac.main(BadExecJavac.java:13)
```

If an external process has not yet completed, the `exitValue()` method will throw an `IllegalThreadStateException`; that's why this program failed.
This is the best [link which I used](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). See all four pages.

**Remember in web application JSP,Servlet runs at server side not at client and `Runtime.exec()` executes commands at the same environment where the command is been executed.  It will only run at the server and not at the client**

**Some links**

1. If you are running code in `JSP` as like mentioned on this [post](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1402078)
2. [Runtime.exec problem with Tomcat  when started as Window Service](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1459593)

Comment: @HlaingMyo: you have typo `String l_Time =  = pData.getTimeStamp();` type `String l_Time = pData.getTimeStamp();`.